# How to calculate radius of ring in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, thickness

I have a stack of cortical bone images, high resolution and binarized. How do I go about calculating the mean inner and outer radii for each image? Here is an example of the kind of images I need to process:
[image]

Comment: I started by calculating the centroid of the white pixels in the x and y directions. I'm thinking I would need that to calculate the distance between the center and the inner and outer perimeters of the bone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be one approach -

```
%// Read in image and conert to binary
im = im2bw(imread('http://s9.postimg.org/aew1l7tvz/4_COPY_copy.png'));
figure, imshow(im), title('Original Image')

%// Fill holes giving us the "outer blob"
outer_blob = imfill(im,'holes');
outer_blob = biggest_blob(outer_blob); %// remove noise
figure, imshow(outer_blob), title('Outer Blob')

%// Get the inner filled blob by "removing" the original image from outer blob
inner_blob = outer_blob & ~im;
inner_blob = biggest_blob(inner_blob); %// remove noise
figure, imshow(inner_blob), title('Inner Blob')

%// Find the equivalent/mean inner and outer radii 
inner_dia  = regionprops(inner_blob,'Equivdiameter');
inner_radius = inner_dia.EquivDiameter/2

outer_dia  = regionprops(outer_blob,'Equivdiameter');
outer_radius = outer_dia.EquivDiameter/2
```

Associated function code -

```
function out = biggest_blob(BW)

%// Find and labels blobs in the binary image BW
[L, num] = bwlabel(BW, 8); 

%// Count of pixels in each blob, basically this should give the area of each blob
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,L(:),1:num)); 

%// Get the label(ind) cooresponding to blob with the maximum area 
%// which would be the biggest blob
[~,ind] = max(counts);

%// Get only the logical mask of the biggest blob by comparing all labels 
%// to the label(ind) of the biggest blob
out = (L==ind);

return;
```

Code run and debug images -

```
inner_radius =
  211.4740
outer_radius =
  267.8926
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for the quick reply and detailed answer.